# How can I rotate an element on an external website?

Tags: javascript

I want to take the logo of google.com and rotate it, not big deal and nothing really important, I just wanna learn JS in a fun way.
When I use the select element tool (Ctrl+Shift+c in chrome) I get that logo's id is "logo", so I'm trying this way:

```
const logo = document.getElementById("logo");
```

But I get this everytime I try:

```
undefined
```

I'd appreciate any help, TY <3

Comment: I am looking at it right now and the logo doesn't have an ID.

Comment: Just a small tip: Tagging such as "// JS" in the title is not needed, the tags that are specified are clear enough most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target it's class, id or an attribute. Assuming you're talking about Google's default search homepage, the class seems to be using a dynamic value (you can still target using that value but your code will not work if you try to run it again when the values have changed) so you could target it's `alt` attribute instead and use the transform `rotate()` css property on it like this:

```
const logo = document.querySelector('img[alt="Google"]');
logo.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
```

The above two lines should rotate the Google logo if you run it in the browser console.

Comment: The syntax for the `transform` is wrong; it should be a string.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for the heads up. Snippet updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you entered that in the JS console.

The result of the `const logo = ...` statement is `undefined`, but that doesn't mean the `const` didn't get assigned (though in case the element doesn't exist, then `logo` did get assigned `undefined`...).

If the element does exist and you follow up with `logo.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)'`, it should work out fine.

As an aside, `document.querySelector("img[alt=Google]")` may be more bullet-proof for Google's front page.

See:

[image]